# Choosing effective function names

Tags: php, coding-style, naming, code-cleanup

I'm looking for advice on writing a good function name as part of a web page I'm developing.  It's coded in PHP and the function basically reassembles array data holding customer attendance information to a music venue (example time, date, entrance, etc) . The function takes in array data and returns the information formatted as a string that includes HTML structuring.

For instance:

```
//function formats array
...
$returnStr = "<span class='bold'>Entrance</span>customerData['entrance']";
```

The reason I ask is that any function name I come up with seems either too verbose or isn't completely clear about what it means.  I have to maintain a lot of code, so I'm trying to choose effective names such that when I revisit code, I can quickly grasp what is going on.

Any online resources or personal insight would be appreciated.

Comment: +1 for asking such a best-practice-oriented question rather than the more common "ZOMG HERES MY CODE WHY IT NOT WORK" trash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no black or white in this case. But I believe that the best practice should be:

- Logical - Describe what the function does
- Comfortable - short and to the point

So you won't have to think on "Wait, what was the name of the function that does X and Y?" and you won't have to write too much code, like: `printMusicVenueFromArray`.

Both the "logical" and "comfortable" aspects are subjective and might be different from one person to another, so as long it's only you that work on that project - do what feels right.

When you have a team of developers working on a single project, consider drawing some guidelines before.

Start by describing the function in words, what's the input, what's the output.
Consider other functions that already exists in your code with similar names (you don't want to get confused).

According to your description:

> function basically reassembles array data holding customer attendance
>   information to a music venue (example time, date, entrance, etc) . The
>   function takes in array data and returns the information formatted as
>   a string that includes HTML structuring.

**Input**
array data holding customer attendance information to a music venue

**Output**
(return) the information formatted as a string that includes HTML structuring.

Usually when I write functions that return something I'll start with `get`, but your function returns HTML string so it's more a `view` function so you can ignore it.

Now you should think on what describes the returned string the most, in my opinion, something like "MusicProfile" or "MusicDetails".

BTW, your quotes conflict.